# Swift: Replace numeric value in string separated by multiple delimiters

Tags: swift, string, replace, delimiter

I am currently using an api with image url strings formatted like this:

```
https://someExampleURL/18px-ImageName.png
```

The numeric value right before "px" is inconsistent, therefore I want to replace this value with a static one in order to load images of the same size.

I was thinking of splitting the string by character "/" and "px" and replacing the numeric value inside the string with "100". What might be the best strategy to achieve this?

Comment: @Xcoder please don't try to edit the question or my answer to include the URL as a link, since the URL doesn't actually work, but it forms an important part of both the Q&A as it shows the requested format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
let link = "https://someexampleurl/18px-ImageName.png"
let newLink = link.replacingOccurrences(of: "/\\d+px", with: "/100px", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, with such a specific URL format, you can use `components(separatedBy:)` to split the URL string by the last `/` character and the remaining part by the first occurence of `px`. Make sure that your URL format doesn't change if you plan to keep using the forced unwrapping.

Once you retrieve the image size, you can use `String.replacingCharacters(in:,with:)` to change the size to a new value.

```
let newImageSize = "100"
let imageUrlString = "https://someExampleURL/18px-ImageName.png"
let imageSize = imageUrlString.components(separatedBy: "/").last!.components(separatedBy: "px").first!
let modifiedImageUrlString = imageUrlString.replacingCharacters(in: imageUrlString.range(of: imageSize)!, with: newImageSize)
```

Result:

> "https://someExampleURL/100px-ImageName.png"

Answer (score 1):

Can you guarantee the number of '/' characters in the URL?

```
'https://someExampleURL/18px-ImageName.png'.split('/')
```

returns the list

```
['https:', '', 'someExampleURL', '18px-ImageName.png']
```

Consequently,

```
'https://someExampleURL/18px-ImageName.png'.split('/')[3].split('px')
```

returns the list

```
['18', '-ImageName.png']
```

That's how to break the string up. All you have to do is substitute the bits you want and concatenate it back together.